# Is there an excel function that returns a range of values based on a condition?

Tags: excel, range, countif

To better illustrate what I am looking for I will give an example. Imagine a spreadsheet with two columns, Priority and Value.

```
P   V
H   x
H   x
M   x
M   y
```

I want to count the number of 'x' in Value if Priority is 'H'.

Countif uses COUNTIF(Range, Criteria) so I'm thinking I need a way to alter the range based on P and be able to use that range of rows in the Value column.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2007 and later, you can use the new COUNTIFS worksheet function, as in something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"H",B2:B5,"x")
```

Comment: Not sure how I skipped over COUNTIFS. This was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following (assuming data in A1:B5)

```
=SUM((A1:A5="H")*(B1:B5 = "x")) //returns 2
```

Note that this must be entered as an array formula (i.e. Press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`)

Comment: Thank you for editing my original. I had to run off to a meeting so I rushed to submit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builtin data filtering in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Set up a third column with a formula that combines the first two columns, for instance,

```
=A2&"^"&B2
```

and then "count" it (according to the conditions you specified) with a cell containing

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C5,"H^x")
```

Comment: While this will likely work, the sheet already has a lot of columns as is and I need to do this in multiple places. Thank you for you input.